# Laravel 5.4 include js and css issue

Tags: php, laravel

I have added in my public folder one folder called js and inside a script.js. In the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('/js/script.js') !!}"></script>
```

and all is working in local but on the server I receive a get error:

```
https://url/js/script.js
```

How is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

you should use {{ }} instead of {!! !!}

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}"></script>
```

`{!! !!}` used for **Displaying Unescaped Data**

> By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through
>   PHP's htmlspecialchars function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not
>   want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

Answer (score 1):

> **1st Simple Way To give the path:** As Per `Laravel 5.4` File Structure `asset` folder inside the `resources` folder So Suppose Your file inside that.  ( `resources/asset/` ) So You Can Use Like Below Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/somestylesheet.css') }}" />
```

---

> **2nd Way You can just pass the path to the style sheet .**

```
{!! HTML::style('css/style.css') !!}
```

> **You can just pass the path to the javascript.**

```
{!! HTML::script('js/script.js'); !!}
```

- Add the following lines in the require section of `composer.json` file and run `composer update`    `"illuminate/html": "5.*"`
- Register the `service provider` in `config/app.php` by adding the following value into the providers array:

  `'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider'`
- Register `facades` by adding these two lines in the `aliases` array:

  `'Form'=> 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade', 
   'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade'`

> **3rd Way Place your `assets` in `public` directory and use the following:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/somestylesheet.css') }}" />
```

---

OR ( Use `URL::to()`  )

---

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ URL::to('css/style.css') }}">

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::to('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> and all is working in local but on the server I receive a get error:

By server, are you referring to a remote server (e.g. VPS)? or [PHP's built-in web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)?

Have you tried running `php artisan cache:clear` as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this for solve issue for `http` and `https` because your script and css no run in `https` url:

First you can create `SchemalessUrlGenerator` file in `App\Libraries`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Libraries;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class SchemalessUrlGenerator extends UrlGenerator
{
    public function __construct(RouteCollection $routes, Request $request)
    {
        parent::__construct($routes, $request);
    }

    public function to($path, $extra = [], $secure = null)
    {
        // First we will check if the URL is already a valid URL. If it is we will not
        // try to generate a new one but will simply return the URL as is, which is
        // convenient since developers do not always have to check if it's valid.
        if ($this->isValidUrl($path)) {
            return $path;
        }
        $scheme = $this->getScheme($secure);
        $extra = $this->formatParameters($extra);
        $tail = implode('/', array_map(
            'rawurlencode', (array) $extra)
        );
        // Once we have the scheme we will compile the "tail" by collapsing the values
        // into a single string delimited by slashes. This just makes it convenient
        // for passing the array of parameters to this URL as a list of segments.
        $root = $this->getRootUrl($scheme);
        if (($queryPosition = strpos($path, '?')) !== false) {
            $query = mb_substr($path, $queryPosition);
            $path = mb_substr($path, 0, $queryPosition);
        } else {
            $query = '';
        }
        return '//' . $this->trimUrl($root, $path, $tail).$query;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getScheme($secure)
    {
        // Don't be smart Laravel... ask the browser?!?!
        // negotiate the schema to be the same as how page was served
        return '//';
    }
}
```

Then you can add `SchemalessUrlGenerator` related code in `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` in `register` method

```
$routes = $this->app['router']->getRoutes();

// // Replace UrlGenerator with SchemalessUrlGenerator that will serve content using "//" instead
// // of "http" or "https"
$schemalessUrlGenerator = new SchemalessUrlGenerator($routes, $this->app->make('request'));
$this->app->instance('url', $schemalessUrlGenerator);
```

Hope this help for you!